# How to get Atom key bindings in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, atom-editor

I find Atom keyboard shortcuts to be more natural to my taste...
I do see some predefined keymaps in WebStorm, but I don't see Atom. I know I can create a new keymap but I do not want to alter things one by one. I also could not find any plugin to do so.

How to transfer all of Atom key binding settings to WebStorm?

Comment: I found out that keymaps are included with the export/import settings in WebStorm, inside a jar file... But I can not find default keymaps of Atom anywhere, neither JSON/CSON nor XML...

Comment: I also figured out that keymaps are stored at .WebStorm<ver>\config\keymaps\...
All I need to do now is Atom Shortcuts for WebStorm in XML, but that'd have to be manually assigned. That's sole problem now.

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm doesn't come with predefined Atom keymap, and no keymaps are contributed by the community... If you miss it, please feel free to file a feature request to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB. Related ticket: [GO-4649](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4649).
So it seems that creating your own keymap per instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html is the only way to go. You can start with a keymap attached to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4649#focus=streamItem-27-2742316-0-0